# Can I disable flick gesture on a WPF Frame?

Tags: wpf, touch, gesture

I am not trying to cripple the program. The program has a master page and a detail page which has a picture viewer that supports flick gesture, and user can flick forward and backward to view the pictures (I implement this by handling the TouchMove event on an Image control).

**The Problem:**  After user navigate from master page to the detail page, he can flick backward to the master page. The flick gesture is a system built-in functionality of the Frame control, I don't have to white any code to enable that gesture. If the finger swipes and leaves screen quickly, the system flick gesture is recognized. If the finger swipe is slow and steady, then the Image control has the change to fire the TouchMove event.

**The question** is how to disable flick gesture on the Frame? I use buttons to navigate between master and detail page so I don't need it.

OS: Windows 7, .NET 4.0.

Comment: Please show relevant XAML. (event, gesture bindings whatever)

Comment: @safetyOtter there is nothing special, write a window with a Frame hosting a page, once you navigate to another page, you can swipe your finger to navigate back to the previous page. On a touch monitor of course. That is what I want to disable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled="False" to your frame?

Comment: It works! But instead of setting this property on the frame, set it on each page to make it work. It is the hosted page that receives the  navigate forward/backward command, not the hosting frame.